# Center action bar title - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, center-align

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"white\">" + "Settings" + "</font>"));
```

[This is how the action bar looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83o1C.jpg)

I'm using these two lines on onCreate method to change action bar title and color but it's aligned to the left, is there a way to center it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setTitle` use a custom toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
     app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



//In your activity file
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Actually I was kinda looking for a way to solve this within these 2 lines without going for a custom one, anyway thanks though